# Does TcpClient.Dispose() closes the TcpClient.GetStream?

Tags: c#, sockets

For closing a TcpClient it's necessary to close the stream. And the usual way of doing that is:

```
        client.GetStream().Close();
        client.Close();
```

so using `client.Close()` by itself is not enough, my question is does the `client.Dispose()` works same as `client.GetStream().Close()` so the closing will be like

```
        client.Dispose();
        client.Close();
```

this is what i understood from reading the [TcpClient reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Sockets/TCPClient.cs,e70aabe5304f5cb1) as the `Dispose` method closes the stream, so am i correct or am i missing something? Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Dispose, should close any object external resources like streams, files and others.

Comment: What makes you think that just `Close()` is not enough? Should be fine IMO. I wouldn't call `Close()` *or* `Dispose()` explicitly usually - I'd use a `using` statement. But just `Dispose()` should be enough.

Comment: so it works same as `TcpClient.GetStream().Close`? note that the `Dispose` belongs to the `TcpClient` not the `NetworkStream`

Comment: @JonSkeet `Close()` only closes stream, dispose from msdn **Releases the managed and unmanaged resources used by the TcpClient.**

Comment: @Karol: `Close()` calls `Dispose` in this case.

Comment: Looking at it from another point of view, I would consider `TcpClient` to be buggy if it _didn't_ clean up the underlying stream.  Relying on consumer code getting hold of your disposable innards and cleaning them up is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @JonSkeet `Close` does not clean the resources imediatly and calling it will keep the stream open for a time so by itself is not enough and won't hurt closing the stream

Comment: @vkr02692: Please give evidence of that. `Close()` calls `Dispose()` - it should be fine. I see no evidence whatsoever that `Close()` keeps the stream open.

Comment: @JonSkeet I just saw this in code. Starange. In my opinion `close()` should only close.

Comment: @Karol: But closing and disposing are equivalent here. Closing the client should close the socket, which *is* releasing the resources...

Comment: From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.getstream?view=netframework-4.7.2 it states in the note: **You must close the NetworkStream when you are through sending and receiving data. Closing TcpClient does not release the NetworkStream.**

Comment: @DrGriff but disposing the client *does* close the stream's connection, so quite a strange pattern. It seems the client owns the actual socket object in use, which gets disposed when the client is disposed (which makes sense), but it means that in an ideal world you need to have the client object hanging around until you're done with the stream.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Close` calls `Dispose`, `Dispose` disposes the stream:

```
IDisposable dataStream = m_DataStream;
if (dataStream != null)
{
    dataStream.Dispose();
}
```

You don't need to call both `Close` and `Dispose`. Choose one.

You can check the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Sockets/TCPClient.cs)

It's quite common for `IDisposable` classes to have another method doing the same as `Dispose`, but with a different, domain-specific name. Very often `IDisposable.Dispose` is implemented explicitly, so that it can be used by `using` statement or after a cast, but doesn't clutter the class' interface.

Comment: yeah i did that at the beginning so i asked, so close by itself will be enough?

Comment: @vkr02692 Yes, `Close` is enough.

Comment: I always found this pattern in the framework very odd - Close just means "I want to close the stream" but Dispose means "I've finished using the class instance". These are not synonymous. Dispose is typically used as the last instruction to an instance, but Close just means "close the stream". Whey should Close() call Dispose() ? (I know it does, but its an interesting conflation).

Comment: @PhillipH why would you want to `Close` without disposing? it won't make sense.

Comment: @PhillipH I only find it confusing when there is also an `Open` method. Of course I can't `Open` a `Dispose`d instance, but `Close`d? Not sure.

Comment: TcpClient is not a sealed class. Just closing its stream doesn't mean I have finished the life-history of the instance. The author of TcpClient hasn't made Close virtual so the inheritor cannot change the behaviour, and the behaviour is destructive. As the consumer of an inherited version of the class I would not expect a simple "close your stream" command to call the Disposer because I haven't told the instance I've finished using it. An inheritor could well have additional non-stream features I want to use in the object lifetime.

Comment: @PhillipH Ultimately `Close` calls `protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)`. You can (and should) override it in derived classes to clean up any other resources. And the documentation is clear here: `TcpClient.Close` "Disposes this TcpClient instance and requests that the underlying TCP connection be closed."

Comment: @JakubLortz - agreed; the inheritor should do this. Its just an unusual to find a class where a method call disposes of the class without a Using or Dispose() explicit call - I never found it confusing, just odd and the OP made me go "hey, yeah, I also found that a bit weird first time I ran into it". Happy Christmas :-)

Comment: that subtle difference in that source code linked on the extra logging Close does vs. Dispose

Answer (score 1):

```
client.Dispose
```

or

```
client.Close
```

does the same. One call is enough

And both closes the Network stream

from MSDN

> Calling this method will eventually result in the close of the associated Socket and will also close the associated NetworkStream that is used to send and receive data if one was created.